# Visual Studio's "Start Without Debugging" equivalent in JetBrains Rider?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, jetbrains-ide, rider

Is there an equivalent of VS's Start Without Debugging in Rider? I know I can "Run" vs. "Debug", but that starts a new instance of IISExpress each time and stops it when I hit "Stop". I want the site to be up and running and allow me to change code and rebuild, then refresh the site, all without having to Run/Stop again. I depend on this behavior in VS. Can Rider do the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Same `Ctrl+F5` key combination works for me in Rider as it used to in VS.

However, I believe what you want is to add a watch build configuration. To do this, edit your `Properties\launchSettings.json` and add a watch profile similar to this one

```json
  "profiles": {
    "my webapp": { ... }
    },
    "my webapp Watch": {
        "commandName": "Executable",
        "executablePath": "dotnet",
        "workingDirectory": "$(ProjectDir)",
        "commandLineArgs": "watch run --local-kestrel=1",
        "environmentVariables": {
            "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
    }
  }
```

after that, select that new profile in the configuration dropdown and hit `Ctrl+F5` to run it without debugger attached.